# Using limits to prove that a subgroup has finite order

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G_\infty = \left(\left\{\dfrac{a}{2^i}  \mid   a \in \mathbb{Z}, i \in \mathbb{N} \right\}, + \right)$, as the group of rationals in $\mathbb{Q}$ with a power of 2 as denominator.
>
> Now consider $X=G_{\infty}/\mathbb{Z}$. Prove $|X| = \infty$ and each proper subgroup of $X$ has finite order.

I'm unsare about the second part, can I use limits in such proofs?

#### Proof

- $X$ has infinite order:

  Asume $X$ has finite order, or $|X| = n$. Then for all $g+\mathbb{Z}$ in $X$, $ng+\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$. However let $g = \dfrac{a}{2^n}$ for a certain $a \not = 0$ then $ng+\mathbb{Z} \not = \mathbb{Z}$.
- For each $A <  X$ then $|A| < \infty$

  I was thinking of proving the following: Let $A \leq X$ then if $|A|=\infty  \Rightarrow A = X$. This is an equivalent statement right?

  So choose an $A\leq X$ and let $|A| = \infty$. Now assume $A \not = X$ then there must exist a certain $\dfrac{a}{2^i} + \mathbb{Z} \in X$ which is not in $A$. Notice how $\dfrac{a}{2^{i+1}}+\mathbb{Z}$ is not in $A$ either. If it would, then so would $\dfrac{a}{2^i}+\mathbb{Z} = \left(\dfrac{a}{2^{i+1}}+\mathbb{Z}\right) + \left(\dfrac{a}{2^{i+1}}+\mathbb{Z}\right)$
  This means that $$\dfrac{a}{2^i}+\mathbb{Z}, \dfrac{a}{2^{i+1}}+\mathbb{Z}, \ldots \not \in A$$

  I'm unsure if I can state the following:

  Then $$\lim_{i\to \infty} \dfrac{a}{2^i} + \mathbb{Z} \not \in A$$
  however $\mathbb{Z} \in A$, contradiction.

Comment: You can't. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: What you can do, however is to recycle your argument to show that $A$ has exactly one element if it is finite.

Comment: hmm clearly algebra $\not = $ analysis :) I'm unsure on how to show that $A$ has exactly one element...

Comment: Well, think about it.Thre is no hurry.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez But like Michael Hardy shows: $\langle \frac{1}{4}+\mathbb{Z} \rangle$ has 4 elements? and is a proper subgroup of $X$?

Answer (score 1):

To prove this group has infinite order, why not just exhibit an infinite sequence of distinct members? Thus:
$$
\frac 1 2,\ \underbrace{\frac 1 4, \frac 3 4},\ \underbrace{\frac 1 8, \frac 3 8,\frac 5 8, \frac 7 8},\ \ldots,\ \underbrace{\frac 1 {2^i}, \frac 3 {2^i}, \frac 5 {2^i}, \ldots, \frac{2^n-1}{2^i}},\ \ldots\ldots
$$

To show every element has finite order, first observe that every element is of the form $\dfrac a {2^i}$ for some $n\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and some $k\in\{1,3,5,7,\ldots,2^i-1\}$ (understanding the fraction to mean the congruence class modulo $1$ to which it belongs). So the problem is to show that the sequence
$$
\frac a {2^i},\  2\frac a {2^i},\  3\frac a {2^i},\  \ldots
$$
ultimately reaches $0.$ But it is $0$ when the integer by which $a/2^i$ is multiplied is itself $2^i.$

ok, So far this shows every cyclic subgroup has finite order. Maybe I'll post something later on how to show that every proper subgroup is cyclic.

It's not hard to show every *finite* subgroup is cyclic. Identify the members of the subgroups with fractions with powers of $2$ as denominators. Their *common*
denominator is a power of $2,$ so the members are
$$
\left\{\frac a {2^n} : a\in\text{some finite set} \right\}.
$$
This is a subset of $\left\{\dfrac 1 {2^n}, \dfrac 3 {2^n}, \dfrac 5 {2^n},\ldots,\dfrac{2^n-1}{2^n}\right\},$ and that is a finite set. Show that that finite set *is* the subgroup. Or even that it includes the subgroup; that is enough.